# Как работает метод read у потока полученного от require("fs").createReadStream?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Пытаясь разобраться в теме потоков я своей целью для экзекуций выбрал поток, который я получал методом `require("fs").createReadStream`, однако, когда я вызываю у него метод `read`, то никакого эффекта не могу заметить, при этом метод `pipe`, который в итоге должен вызывать внутри метод `read` работает исправно.

Не понятно почему метод read возвращает null

```
const fs = require("fs");
var stream = fs.createReadStream("info.txt");
console.log(stream.read()); //null
console.log(stream.read(1)); //null
```

При этом метод pipe выполняет всё так как должен

```
const fs = require("fs");
var stream = fs.createReadStream("info.txt");
stream.pipe(process.stdout); //text from file
```

Comment: добавь пример кода, который работает и который нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У потоков чтения есть [два режима работы](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_two_reading_modes).

1. Получать данные автоматически
2. Получать вручную

Добавление обработчика `readable` автоматически переводит в ручной режим и данные можно получать с помощью метода [`.read`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_read_size)

```
const fs = require("fs");
var stream = fs.createReadStream("info.txt");
stream.on('readable', () => {
    console.log(stream.read()); 
    console.log(stream.read(1));
});
```